# Collection view working on both iphone but half showing in ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uicollectionview

In my application,I am using Collection view as i'd take in Xib.now there is image of array come from server side. And they are correctly seen in both iphone 3.5 and 4 inch screen.But when i select device as ipad it seem like this:

[image]

There are three rows appear and i don't know how to solve this problem.I want only one row which will be scrollable.

Here is my code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [imagArr count];
}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    QBAssetsCollectionViewCell *cell = (QBAssetsCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"QBAssetsCollectionViewCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSDictionary *imageName = [[imagArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Content"];
    NSString *sr = [imageName objectForKey:@"text"];
    cell.Img.image = [self decodeBase64ToImage:sr];
    //[cell updateCell];

    return cell;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSLog(@"%ld",(long)indexPath.row);

    NSDictionary *imageName = [[imagArr objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectForKey:@"Content"];
    NSString *sr = [imageName objectForKey:@"text"];
    cloud.image= [self decodeBase64ToImage:sr];
    [self.collectionView setHidden:YES];
}
```

Comment: Is `AutoLoLayout` enabled?

Comment: Set frame for iPad ..........and check Autolayout

Comment: @Pawan-Systematix its all correct bro

Comment: Have you found the solution?

Comment: @ParvendraSingh not solved brother

Comment: You have 2 xib separate iPhone and iPad???? @user3218052

Comment: oks then check once your xib's frame in inspector .....

Comment: @ParvendraSingh means what?

Comment: @ParvendraSingh xib is appear but only collection view item shoul come in one row and in horizontal but it is not

Comment: you need to add xib for iPad... ok then you have to give that class reference to it ....i think you miss that

Comment: @ParvendraSingh i add my xib and class reference also given but no result found

Comment: will you show me your iPad xib after that i will tell something

Comment: @ParvendraSingh i mention it in my question

Comment: @user3218052 this is your simulator screen as your output... i need how to set your xib. in your project

Comment: @ParvendraSingh i done this i reduce height of collection view and data is loaded horizontal and in single row

Comment: @ParvendraSingh but i get problem when i resize collection cell from (50,50) to (100,100) and by that image is in random size some are big some are small and while scrolling image is change

Comment: You use an UIImageView on UICollectionView ... there are a property of  UIImageView that [imgView setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleToFitt]; use it in cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @ParvendraSingh not working bro on scrolling horizontal image is not in its original size and sometime it appear in its original as (100,100).so what can i do